Checksum of addr() descriptor
I'm trying to get the checksum of my descriptor (addr(tb1qsvmygjlhq2p9ap262fwdfq3ptfjqlg2s9gcx58wazdge07kwu26q9guuh2)) using the getdescriptorinfo method, but I'm getting an error:

-5: Address is not valid

BIP385 is too sparse to explain what's wrong with my address.
I don't have the ability to use other handle functions like wsh(), I just want to track utxo addresses on the wallet. I'm connecting to bitcoind v0.26 using Btcd Golang library

Is bitcoind running in testnet mode?

Yes, the problem was that I was accessing the regtest node. This is my carelessness, thank you. If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as a solution.

Bitcoin Core only accepts addresses in its addr() descriptors that match the chain type it is running for.
So if bitcoind is running with e.g. -regtest, it will only accept regtest addresses, not testnet addresses.
